# Find different records in 2 tables mysql

Tags: mysql

Suppose, I have 2 tables, sport_class and music_class.

[image]

I want to find amount of student who are in music_class but not in sport_class.
The expect result is : 2 (Julia and Peter) . Please help me, thanks.

**This is what I have tried :**

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT x.name) AS diff_user 
from sport_class x RIGHT 
JOIN music_class y ON x.name = y.name 
WHERE x.name != y.name;
```

Comment: Considering you don't seem to want to try yourself; what's your budget?

Comment: use `NOT IN`....besides, showing what you have tried so far would be helpful!!

Comment: @h2ooooooo: I already tried few hours, but I failed. My problem is bigger than these and more complicated but i just want the basic concept. Please help me.

Comment: @NoobEditor: NOT IN is a good idea. Thanks. This is what i have tried but fial : SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT x.name) AS diff_user from sport_class  x RIGHT JOIN music_class y ON x.name = y.name WHERE x.name != y.name;

Comment: select * from music_class where name not in (select name from sport_class);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select * 
from music_class 
where name NOT IN (select name from sport_class);
```

This should work for your case. Next time please add what you tried in the question itself rather than in comments (when asking the question itself)

Comment: Success now. Thank @amitchhajer

Answer (score 2):

Below query will provide you fast results, even it will provide you quick results if you table size is large.

```
SELECT 
COUNT(distinct m.name) 
FROM music_class m 
LEFT JOIN sport_class s 
ON m.name=s.name 
WHERE s.name IS NULL;
```

Note: For better results there should be index on name column.

Comment: on the contrary....for tables of small size, both `subquery` and `Joins` take more or less same time mate!! :)

Comment: @TapiYuki : i added an explanation why your logic fails, do understand it to avoid future logical errors of same kind! :)

Answer (score 1):

Understand **why your query fails** ( *its always a good approach to understand your error first* )

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT x.name) AS diff_user 
from sport_class x RIGHT 
JOIN music_class y ON x.name = y.name 
WHERE x.name != y.name;
```

You give the join clause as `x.name = y.name` but then `where` clause is totally contradictory to it 
`x.name != y.name`,

So, `where` clause will give you `!=` result set and then `Join` will try to filter it for `x.name = y.name`, so, output would be NULL set i guess in your case.

**Solution**

Both the solutions given by Zafar and Amit would work for you!! :)